# Using BeautifulSoup to parse lines separated by <br> tags?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a page that looks like this:

```
Company A<br />
123 Main St.<br />
Suite 101<br />
Someplace, NY 1234<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
Company B<br />
456 Main St.<br />
Someplace, NY 1234<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Sometimes there are two rather than three "br" tags separating the entries.  How would I use BeautifulSoup to parse through this document and extract the fields?  I'm stumped because the bits of text that I need are not contained in paragraph (or similar) tags that I can simply iterate through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have this HTML fragment, just use a regex to replace `<br />` followed by an optional newline by a single newline, then split on multiple newlines. This should result in multiple individual paragraphs which you can process manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's not as simple as just using a regex.  I've simplified the above document to better illustrate my question.  The actual document has a jumble of HTML formatting tags and the like.

Comment: But you don't *care* about the document, just the part separated by `<br />` tags. Use BeatifulSoup to extract that part first.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted your answer; I appreciate the help.  I will try a couple of ideas based on your suggestion.  I was just hoping that BeautifulSoup would have eliminated the need for manual parsing.  Thank you.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is good for the tags that deal with structure and style, but `<br />` doesn't fall into either of those.

Comment: While I probably would have preferred to work with Michal's answer, I didn't see it until after I completed my project.  I was able to do what I needed using your suggestion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into the `.strings`attribute found in tags, then use "\n".join() on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a little bit of manipulation first before anything. eg change all newlines to blanks, then substitute 2 occurrences and more of `<br />` to some other delimiter like `|`. after that you can get your fields.

```
html="""
Company A<br />
123 Main St.<br />
Suite 101<br />
Someplace, NY 1234<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
Company B<br />
456 Main St.<br />
Someplace, NY 1234<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
"""
import re
newhtml=html.replace("\n","")
pat=re.compile("(<br \/>){2,}",re.DOTALL|re.M)
print pat.sub("|",newhtml)
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
Company A<br />123 Main St.<br />Suite 101<br />Someplace, NY 1234|Company B<br />456 Main St.<br />Someplace, NY 1234|
```

Now your company information are separated by pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this function:

```
def partition_by(pred, iterable):
    current = None
    current_flag = None
    chunk = []
    for item in iterable:
        if current is None:
            current = item
            current_flag = pred(current)
            chunk = [current]
        elif pred(item) == current_flag:
            chunk.append(item)
        else:
            yield chunk
            current = item
            current_flag = not current_flag
            chunk = [current]
    if len(chunk) > 0:
        yield chunk
```

Add something to check for being a `<br />` tag or newline:

```
def is_br(bs):
    try:
        return bs.name == u'br'
    except AttributeError:
        return False

def is_br_or_nl(bs):
    return is_br(bs) or u'\n' == bs
```

(Or whatever else is more appropriate... I'm not that good with BeautifulSoup.)

Then use `partition_by(is_br_or_nl, cs)` to yield (for `cs` set to `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(your_example_html).childGenerator()`)

```
[[u'Company A'],
 [<br />],
 [u'\n123 Main St.'],
 [<br />],
 [u'\nSuite 101'],
 [<br />],
 [u'\nSomeplace, NY 1234'],
 [<br />, u'\n', <br />, u'\n', <br />, u'\n', <br />],
 [u'\nCompany B'],
 [<br />],
 [u'\n456 Main St.'],
 [<br />],
 [u'\nSomeplace, NY 1234'],
 [<br />, u'\n', <br />, u'\n', <br />, u'\n', <br />]]
```

That should be easy enough to process.

To generalise this, you'd probably have to write a predicate to check whether its argument is something you care about... Then you could use it with `partition_by` to have everything else lumped together. Note that the things which you care about are lumped together as well -- you basically have to process every item of every second list produced by the resulting generator, starting with the first one which includes things you care about.

Answer (score -1):

I have slimier issue .this how i solved

```
html=html.replace('<br>','<br />')
```