# Using beautifulsoup to separate strings separated by `<br>`

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get some data from a website that uses `<br>`. In the html parsed using beautifulsoup4 sometimes I have the following pattern:

```
"<p class=some_class>text_1. text_2 (text_3<span class=GramE>)</span> 
<br> 
text_4,<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Arial Unicode MS"'> 
</span>text_5.</p>"
```

But if the website was written in a nicer way, it would have looked like:

```
"<p class=some_class>text_1. text_2(text_3<span class=GramE>)</span 
</p> <p class=some_class>
text_4,<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Arial Unicode MS"'> 
</span>text_5.</p>
```

To extract the strings I want, I would have extracted all text within each `<p>`.
However, now the strings I want to separate are separated by `<br>`.

My question is the following: how can I use `<br>` to disentangle the parts of the string I am interested in? I mean, I want something like `[text_1.+text_2+text_3, text_4+text_5.]`.

I'm explicitly asking about the use of `<br>` since is the only element I have found that separates the strings I'm interested. Moreover, in some others parts of the website, I have `<br/>` separating the strings I'm interested in, instead of `<br>`.

I cannot solve this by using the replace() function since my object is a Tag froom bs4. Also, using find("br") from bs4 gives me "`<br/>`" and not the text I want. In this way, the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305191/using-beautifulsoup-to-parse-lines-separated-by-br-tags) are not exactly what I want. I think that one way would be to transform the tag from bs4 that I have to html, then change the "`<br/>`" using replace() function, and finally transform it back to a bs4 element. However, I do not know how to make this change, and I also want to know if there is an easier and shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found but it's long and inefficient since it does not use any feature of bs4. Though, it works.

```
html_doc = """
"<p class=some_class>text_1. text_2 (text_3<span class=GramE>)</span> 
<br> 
text_4,<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Arial Unicode MS"'> 
</span>text_5.</p>"
"""

def replace_br(soup_object):
    html1=str(soup_object)
    html1=html1.replace("<br>", "</p> <p>")
    soup_html1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'html.parser')
    return soup_html1.find_all("p")

replace_br(html_doc)
[<p class="some_class">text_1. text_2 (text_3<span class="GramE">)</span>
</p>, <p> 
text_4,<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Arial Unicode MS"'>
</span>text_5.</p>]
```